# discord.py - get footer content from embed

Tags: python

```
#Delete Message Command
@bot.command()
async def deletemessage(ctx, *, messageid):
    await Webhooklogging(c['webhook'],f"{ctx.author} | {ctx.guild.id} -> {c['prefix']}deletemessage {messageid}")
    adminz = []
    for userid in users["users"]:
        if userid["isbotmod"] == "True":
            adminz.append(int(userid["userid"]))
    if ctx.message.author.id in adminz:
        for server in servers["servers"]:
            guild: Guild = bot.get_guild(int(server["guildid"]))
            if guild:
                channel: TextChannel = guild.get_channel(int(server["channelid"]))
                if channel:
                    perms: Permissions = channel.permissions_for(guild.get_member(bot.user.id))
                    if perms.manage_messages:
                            #get last 50 messages, if contains embed then get embed footer
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = f'Error!',
            description = "You are not permitted to use this command!",
            color=0x662a85)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

i have this code so far, and i want to be able to get the last 50 messages in channel, check if they have an embed and if they do get the embed footer content

i tried to use this code to get the last 50 messages then check for embed

```
for msg in ctx.channel.history(limit=50):
    embedFromMessage = msg.embeds[0]
    print(embedFromMessage.footer)
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `await channel.channel_history(limit=limit)` to attain the desired amount of messages!

Also, you can just use `ctx.guild`.

Comment: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'TextChannel' object has no attribute 'channel_history'

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
@bot.command(name="epic_test_command")
async def epic_test_command(ctx):
    messages = [msg async for msg in ctx.channel.history(limit=51)]
    for message in messages:
        if len(message.embeds) != 0:
            # Message has Embed
            for embed in message.embeds:
                print(embed.footer)
```

It gets the last 51 messages in the channel, (1 extra because you running the command is a message), then checks all the messages for embeds, if it does, it checks each embed and prints the footer content.

Cheers, Eric